# Deleted plugins displays error message

Tags: plugins

I made the mistake of manually deleting plugin directories in the plugins folder and now I see error messages on the plugins admin page:

> The plugin xyz.php has been
>   deactivated due to an error: Plugin file does not exist.

Is there a way to get rid of this error message? Maybe it's a cache issue?

Comment: I have a similar error in my development environment, have you modified the plugins or wp-content directory in `wp-config.php`?

Answer (score 0):

You can do 1 thing... Re install that plugin and deactivate it via Wordpress Backend...
And yes, looks like it is cache issue otherwise these messages are not viewable more than 1 time.